# updating() function affected by an INSTEAD OF trigger

Tags: oracle, view, plsql, triggers

We use a view to abstract the fact that our database design is changing... the old, legacy code had all user data dumped into one denormalized table; the new design breaks the data apart in a normal design.  For a number of reasons (some legit, others not), some of our new development had to be done against the new database, and therefore the user data has to be kept in sync until the new database becomes the authoritative source for user data.  It's an incestuous mess, but it's what I'm stuck with.

We chose to use an instead-of trigger on the view to write to both databases... the only other option was to write a trigger on the tables of the authoritative source, but that could have introduced unintended side-effects into the existing code.

The problem:  If I don't include, say, a status_date in an update to the table directly, the function `updating('status_date')` returns false in any triggers on the views.  However, the instead-of trigger must include the status_date field in its update queries, so it will always appear to have been "set" to the same value.

For example, our status date field in the current user table is triggered to update automatically when the user's status changes if it isn't included in the update:

```
-- Don't change the status date if a date has been explicitly set
if (not updating('status_date')) then 
   :new.status_date := sysdate;
end if;
```

If I update the table directly as:

```
update user_status set
   status = 'GONE',
   status_date = to_date('20170101','yyyymmdd')    
where user_id = '123456';
```

The table will use 2017/01/01 as the date.  However, leaving the date out will trigger it to sysdate.

```
-- The trigger will set status_date to sysdate
update user_status set
   status = 'GONE'    
where user_id = '123456';
```

In the view trigger, I have to update everything:

```
update user_status set
   status = :new.status,
   status_date = :new.status_date
where user_id = :new.user_id;
```

But this causes `updating('status_date')` to always return true in the user_status table trigger - I have to check the values, and if they're the same, I have to assume the date isn't being set.

```
-- Don't change the status date if a date has been explicitly set
if (:new.status_date = :old.status_date) then 
   :new.status_date := sysdate;
end if;
```

For the most part, it works the same.  Except I lose the ability to keep the current date by setting it explicitly - the following two queries now look identical, and both will update the status date.  However, only the second one should :(

```
-- Not setting the date, trigger will use sysdate
update v_user_status set
   status = 'GONE',
   status_date = status_date     
where user_id = '123456';

-- I'm correcting the status, but I need to keep the original date
update v_user_status set
   status = 'GONE' 
where user_id = '123456';
```

How can I keep the "not updating" status of a field when updating a table from the view trigger?

Comment: I'm slightly confused. With the `not updating` check in the table trigger, both view updates set the date to today. With the equality check neither updates it. But essentially you just want updating the view to work the same as updating the table directly, whether you set the status date to itself (stays the same), set it to a specific date, or don't set it (so it goes to sysdate)?

Answer (score 0):

If you revert your table trigger to use `not updating()`, you can then use the same check in your view trigger to decide which value to use, setting a local variable and then using that in the table update:

```
...
declare
   l_status_date date;
begin
   if (not updating('status_date')) then 
      l_status_date := sysdate;
   else
      l_status_date := :new.status_date;
   end if;
   update user_status set
      status = :new.status,
      status_date = l_status_date
   where user_id = :new.user_id;
end;
/
```

The table trigger will always see it as updating; but it gets the same column value as it would have got or generated anyway. Using the equality check in the table trigger does not work though when you set it to itself, as that is still true when you don't want to be.

Set up with some dummy DDL and DML:

```
create table user_status (user_id varchar2(7), status varchar2(6), status_date date);

create trigger user_status_trig
before update on user_status
for each row
begin
   -- Don't change the status date if a date has been explicitly set
   if (not updating('status_date')) then 
      :new.status_date := sysdate;
   end if;
end;
/

create view v_user_status as select * from user_status;

create trigger v_user_status_trig
instead of update on v_user_status
declare
   l_status_date date;
begin
   if (not updating('status_date')) then 
      l_status_date := sysdate;
   else
      l_status_date := :new.status_date;
   end if;
   update user_status set
      status = :new.status,
      status_date = l_status_date
   where user_id = :new.user_id;
end;
/

insert into user_status values ('123456', 'NEW', date '2015-01-01');
commit;
```

Updating the table directly with the three scenarios (rollback between each):

```
update user_status set
   status = 'GONE',
   status_date = status_date
where user_id = '123456';
select * from user_status where user_id = '123456';

USER_ID STATUS STATUS_DAT
------- ------ ----------
123456  GONE   2015-01-01

update user_status set
   status = 'GONE',
   status_date = to_date('20170101','yyyymmdd')    
where user_id = '123456';
select * from user_status where user_id = '123456';

USER_ID STATUS STATUS_DAT
------- ------ ----------
123456  GONE   2017-01-01

update user_status set
   status = 'GONE'    
where user_id = '123456';
select * from user_status where user_id = '123456';

USER_ID STATUS STATUS_DAT
------- ------ ----------
123456  GONE   2017-04-21
```

Repeating the same scenarios via the view:

```
-- Setting the date to itself
update v_user_status set
   status = 'GONE',
   status_date = status_date     
where user_id = '123456';
select * from user_status where user_id = '123456';

USER_ID STATUS STATUS_DAT
------- ------ ----------
123456  GONE   2015-01-01

-- Setting the date, trigger will use that
update v_user_status set
   status = 'GONE',
   status_date = date '2017-01-01'     
where user_id = '123456';
select * from user_status where user_id = '123456';

USER_ID STATUS STATUS_DAT
------- ------ ----------
123456  GONE   2017-01-01

-- I'm correcting the status, but I need to keep the original date
update v_user_status set
   status = 'GONE' 
where user_id = '123456';
select * from user_status where user_id = '123456';

USER_ID STATUS STATUS_DAT
------- ------ ----------
123456  GONE   2017-04-21
```